"かたしなくたって" usage?

最悪だ！よりによってあんな[揶揄]{からか}いかたしなくたって。。。こんなになったのはお前のせいなのに！

The character is ranting out after making a mistake and getting teased out by お前. As I understand the second part is "Things turned like this because of you!" but what does 揶揄いかたしなくたって mean?
揶揄い かた　しなく...?

He is saying 揶揄い方をしなくても and I believe it means the same as からかわなくても.

Please check you copied the sentence correctly. Isn't there そんな or something?

@naruto sorry which part?

Is it supposed to be よりによってそんな揶揄いかた?

Yes, そんな揶揄い【からかい】方【かた】(を)しなくたって(いいだろう) makes sense ("You don't have to mock me in such a way!"). Without そんな, this sentence doesn't seem grammatical. Or this may be a typo for some difference sentence...

Oh I see! It was actually あんな that was missing
